# sql server and long date time

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, datetime, bigint

HI:
I need to convert a bigint filed in database to equivalent datatime
i couldn't do this from sqlserver nor visual studio
i have tried ticks but its not useful
any idea?
thanks alot

Comment: Please post examples of the bigint values in your database

Comment: A useful date format for bigint might be "yyyymmddhhmmssmmm". It would be sortable and human readable.

Comment: the values in the database looks:1276162464406 and 1277290809250 but I don't know the equivalent values in datetime I have just arrived here, and theses don't look like ticks

Answer (score 0):

Why not just like in SQL Server: get minutes and add them to (dateTime.AddMinutes) to 1900-01-01 ?

[Convert .NET Ticks to SQL Server DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2313236/convert-net-ticks-to-sql-server-datetime)

(we know that at 1900-01-01 ticks count was 599266080000000000)

```
        long tNow = 634024345696365272;
        long t1900 = 599266080000000000;

        double minutes = (tNow - t1900) * Math.Pow((double)10,-7) / 60;
        var dataTime = DateTime.Parse("1900-01-01").AddMinutes(Math.Round(minutes));
```