# How to convert a SQL field stored as a tick into a date

Tags: sql, date, select

I am exporting info from a database that has field with a birthdate stored as a tick. I need to convert this to a regular date. I can either do it in the SQL statement (if there is a way?) or convert it into excel since I will import my data there?

EDIT: Sorry, not very familiar with ticks, so wasn't sure what info to include. The database is postgreSQL. Just putting it in a format mm/dd/yyyy is fine (excel should understand that).

Comment: 'tick' is pretty non-specific. How fast does your click tick, and what's its epoch?

Comment: you mean unix timestamp?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert .NET Ticks to SQL Server DateTime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2313236/convert-net-ticks-to-sql-server-datetime)

Answer (score 4):

You need to convert the .NET ticks to UNIX Epoch and then to a postgreSQL timestamp.

```
to_timestamp((("date" - 621355968000000000) / 10000000))
```

This code will work with version 9 and above

Comment: This expression loose milliseconds. Compare: `SELECT to_timestamp(((636892826050036451 - 621355968000000000) / 10000000.0)) as with_milliseconds, to_timestamp(((636892826050036451 - 621355968000000000) / 10000000)) as without_milliseconds`