# How to convert .NET DateTime.Ticks value into DateTime in SQL Query?

Tags: sql, datetime

I am having a column in sql table that holds the value DateTime.Ticks as bigint.
Now, I would like convert this bigint value into datetime in sql query can one help me to proceed?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert .NET Ticks to SQL Server DateTime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2313236/convert-net-ticks-to-sql-server-datetime)

Answer (score 1):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2313516/395659):

```
Declare @TickValue bigint
Declare @Days float

Set @TickValue = 634024345696365272 
Select @Days = @TickValue * POWER(10.00000000000,-7) / 60 / 60 / 24

Select DATEADD(d, Cast(@Days As int), Cast('0001-01-01' As DATE)) 
    + Cast( (@Days - FLOOR(@Days)) As DateTime)
```

Comment: thanks, but Date is not recognised in sql server 2005, also i followed the link that you said in prev post.. and got this

Comment: Use Datetime instead: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/09/12/sql-server-get-date-and-time-from-current-datetime-sql-in-sixty-seconds-025-video/

Comment: tried with Date its working in 2008 Sql server but same it is not working in the sql server 2014 what will be the issue , i moved my project from sql server 2008 to 2014 now it is not crashing.