# Convert specific BigInt to DateTime in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, bigint, dateadd

I have bigInt: `635307578922100000` which I need to convert to `DateTime`.

I've tried few ways to do this:

```
SELECT 
    DATEADD(S, CONVERT(bigint,635307578922100000) / 1000, CONVERT(DATETIME, '1-1-1970 00:00:00'))
```

and:

```
SELECT 
    DATEADD(ms, 635307578922100000 / 86400000, (635307578922100000 / 86400000) +25567)
```

While I found the codes above work with `bigInts` like: `1283174502729`, with my bigInt I get the following error:

> Msg 8115 ...   Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data
>   type datetime.

Does anyone have any idea how to solve it?

Comment: What would be your expected result for the given input '635307578922100000'

Comment: It looks like these are ticks. Possible duplicate of [Convert .NET Ticks to SQL Server DateTime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2313236/convert-net-ticks-to-sql-server-datetime) - using the answer here gives `2016-07-26 09:12:00.000`

Comment: You need to convert this value to number of hours since 01.01.1900 00:00:00, it's the maximum  datepart precision which fits `int `. Then add ms left.

Comment: what is that date?  Even If it is in microseconds, it is still 20,000 years+

Comment: @Bridge I could never think of it myself. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some calculations that can calculate the bigint to a datetime.

```sql
SELECT
tick.value

-- Subtrack the amount of ticks for 1900-01-01 and divide that number by the ticks in 1 day.
-- Then cast or convert that smaller number to a datetime
-- But only accurate to the second.
-- 864000000000 = (10000000 * 24 * 60 * 60)
 , CAST((tick.value - 599266080000000000) / 864000000000 AS datetime) as DateTimeCalc1

-- Subtrack the amount of ticks for 1900-01-01 and divide by the ticks in 1 minute.
-- Then add that smaller number as minutes to 1900-01-01
-- Only accurate to the minute
 , DATEADD(MINUTE, ((tick.value - 599266080000000000) / 600000000), CAST('1900-01-01' AS DATETIME)) as DateTimeCalc2

-- Same method as for DateTimeCalc2, but include the milliseconds.
-- Accurate to the millisecond
 , DATEADD(MILLISECOND, FLOOR((((tick.value - 599266080000000000)/10000)%60000)), DATEADD(MINUTE, FLOOR((tick.value - 599266080000000000)/600000000), CAST('1900-01-01' AS DATETIME))) as DateTimeCalc3

FROM (values 
  (convert(bigint,635307578922100000))
 ,(convert(bigint,599266080000000000))
 ,(convert(bigint,630823257457000000))
 ,(convert(bigint,646602048000000000))
) AS tick(value);
```

**Result:**

```
value               DateTimeCalc1           DateTimeCalc2           DateTimeCalc3
------------------ ----------------------- ----------------------- -----------------------
635307578922100000 2014-03-18 16:44:52.207 2014-03-18 16:44:00.000 2014-03-18 16:44:52.210
599266080000000000 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000
630823257457000000 2000-01-01 12:15:45.697 2000-01-01 12:15:00.000 2000-01-01 12:15:45.700
646602048000000000 2050-01-01 00:00:00.000 2050-01-01 00:00:00.000 2050-01-01 00:00:00.000
```

With a bit of tampering those datetimes can be truncated or rounded on the seconds.

```
SELECT tick.value

-- Truncated
, CAST(CONVERT(varchar, CAST((tick.value - 599266080000000000) / 864000000000 AS datetime),20) AS datetime) as DateTimeTruncated

-- Rounded
, CAST(CAST(CAST((tick.value - 599266080000000000) / 864000000000 AS datetime) as datetime2(0)) AS datetime) as DateTimeRounded

-- For dates between 1981-12-14 and 2118-01-19, one could add seconds to 2050-01-01. 
, DATEADD(SECOND, ((tick.value - 646602048000000000) / 10000000), cast('2050-01-01' as datetime)) as DateTimeSecondsAdded

FROM (values 
(630823257457000000),
(635307578922100000),
(662380857456770000)
) tick(value);
```

Comment: Perfect solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I think it's in ticks (yields 2014-03-18 16:44:52.210). Here is solution:

```
SELECT DATEADD(
    MILLISECOND,
    FLOOR(((635307578922100000-599266080000000000)%(10000000*60))/10000),
    DATEADD(
        MINUTE,
        FLOOR((635307578922100000-599266080000000000)/(10000000*60)),
        '01-01-1900'))
```

This magic value 599266080000000000 is number of ticks between 0001-01-01 and 1900-01-01 calculated in PowerShell as follows:

```
([DateTime]::Parse('1900-01-01')-[DateTime]::MinValue).Ticks
```

Conversions are required, because DATEADD won't work with bigint (requires int). SQL Server DateTime is also limited to 1 January 1753.