# Unknown SQL Server time or timestamp, what kind is this

Tags: sql-server, datetime, timestamp, converters

In a SQL Server Database, I have some data relative to date and times stored. I have two columns : StartTime and EndTime, which contains two values :

```
635193180000000000
```

into StartTime and

```
635193216000000000
```

into EndTime.

I have searched how to convert this into "classic time" like "September 04th 2013" but it is not Unix time and I don't know which format it is..?

Comment: What is the data type of those columns?

Comment: try this link [unix to datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507649/convert-unix-epoch-timestamp-to-tsql-datetime)

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen it is bigint

Comment: @TejinderSingh thank you but even using the answer method I don't get something coherent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found the solution thanks to this question : [Convert specific BigInt to DateTime in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38583963/convert-specific-bigint-to-datetime-in-t-sql) .

It uses .NET Ticks, which begins from 01-01-1900 midnight.. Different from standard UNIX time !

So `635193180000000000` gives `2013-11-06​ 07:00:00.000` .

Answer (score 0):

try using this:-

```sql
select dateadd(s, convert(bigint, 1283174502729) / 1000, convert(datetime, '1-1-1970 00:00:00'))
```

Comment: @Alex you can vote my answer, if you found little helpful