# Smarterstats API Convert DateTicks to Datetime using SQL

Tags: sql-server

I am using SmarterStats APi and one of the field in response is DateTicks and the value is in long integer 636231456000000000 
I need to convert that to date and that should be today's date 2017-02-20
There is no documentation and their support is not very good.

So my question is how would a value like 636231456000000000 convert to 2017-02-20?

Comment: Have you tested if the DateTicks is the same as .NET DateTime.Ticks?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: It appears to be that definition.  I checked it at http://tickstodatetime.com/

Comment: So How to convert that in datetime using Sql

Comment: I marked this question as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2313236/convert-net-ticks-to-sql-server-datetime which discusses the same issue.

Comment: That didn't work .  I replace the value with mine. Got an error ... The data types date and datetime are incompatible in the add operator. And after fixing the type it still failed