# How to convert unix epoch format date to UTC in SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, unix-timestamp

I am having this format of datetime 1610382439.I am looking sql query to convert it to UTC time.

Comment: The query will be different on different RDBMS, which one are you using? MySQL? PostgreSQL? Oracle? ...?

Comment: I am using sql as language and Mysql as the product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to add those seconds to 1970-01-01. The `datetime` datatype does not adjust for DST:

```
select cast('1970-01-01' as datetime) + interval 1610382439 second
-- 2021-01-11 16:27:19
```

Comment: I am getting error Parse exception at 'datetime' while running as sql query in azure databricks notebook

Comment: Got it, thank you :)

Comment: Is it MySQL or something else?

Comment: yes, this query works for me                                                                                       select cast('1970-01-01' as date) + interval 1610382439 second

Comment: You could accept the answer if it helped

Answer (score 0):

In SQL server and .net world it called ticks. You can take a look at this link which shows how to convert it:
[Convert .NET Ticks to SQL Server DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2313236/convert-net-ticks-to-sql-server-datetime)