# SQL Convert int64/Time to Date

Tags: sql

I have a SQL table with a column of `varchar` datatype that contains dates in timestamp format.

```
AccessId    Date                 ComputerName   NumberOfTries
-------------------------------------------------------------
    1       132926085611026702   TESTE                1
```

When I use the command

```
[datetime]::FromFileTime('132926085611026702')
```

in PowerShell, I can get properly the data:

```
Thursday, March 3, 2022 4:03:42 PM
```

But I would like to know how I do this direct conversion through SQL to use in Power BI

Comment: "I have a SQL table with a column in varchar format that gives me dates in timestamp format." - why aren't you using correctly-typed columns?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert .NET Ticks to SQL Server DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2313236/convert-net-ticks-to-sql-server-datetime)

Answer (score 0):

Given that `DateTime.FromFileTime(Int64)` handles `1601-01-01 00:00:00Z`-based values....

> A Windows file time is a 64-bit value that represents the number of 100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since 12:00 midnight, January 1, 1601 A.D. (C.E.) Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).

...then you need to use `CONVERT( bigint, "Date" )`, and then pass that into `DATEADD` with `nanosecond` and '1601-01-01 00:00:00':

```sql
SELECT
    DATEADD( nanosecond, CONVERT( bigint, "Date" ), CONVERT( datetime2(7), '1601-01-01 00:00:00' ) )
FROM
    myTable
```

Comment: Still in error. 

Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.