# How to convert ticks to datetime in Elastic SQL?

Tags: sql, elasticsearch

I want to group elastic entities by month. In order to do that I need to transform the `Created` column data type from `ticks` to `datetime` and then extract the month with `MONTH_NAME` function and then group. For this, I have managed to create the following query:

```
SELECT
  MONTH_NAME(CAST((Created - 621355968000000000)::double / 10000000 / 24 / 60 / 60 AS DATETIME)),
  COUNT(*)
FROM "{elastic-source}"
WHERE Created >= 638081280000000000 AND Created <= 638395776000000000
GROUP BY MONTH_NAME(CAST((Created - 621355968000000000)::double / 10000000 / 24 / 60 / 60 AS DATETIME))
```

This should give me the count of entities for 2023 grouped by the name of the month. The problem is that the `CAST` gives me 1970-01-01 for all entities. I followed the answer here [Convert .NET Ticks to SQL Server DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2313236/convert-net-ticks-to-sql-server-datetime), but changed the ticks I substract, because in SQL Server the date starts from `1900-01-01` (`599266080000000000`) and in elastic it starts from `1970-01-01` (`621355968000000000`).

I've also found that `int` cannot be casted to `datetime` in Elastic SQL. I've tried the following:

```
SELECT CAST(0 AS DATETIME)
SELECT CAST(1 AS DATETIME)
SELECT CAST(1000 AS DATETIME)
```

All results return `1970-01-01`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was dividing by `10000000 / 24 / 60 / 60` and the correct formula is to divide only by 10,000:

```
SELECT
  MONTH_NAME(CAST((Created - 621355968000000000) / 10000 AS DATETIME)) as month,
  COUNT(*)
FROM "{elastic-source}"
WHERE Created >= 638081280000000000 AND Created <= 638395776000000000
GROUP BY month
```

And about that:

> I've also found that int cannot be casted to datetime in Elastic SQL. I've tried the following

This turns out to be incorrect. The problem here was that `0`, `1` and `1000`  were too small values and that's why they all ended as `1970-01-01`.

I used this website to cast ticks to `dateime`: https://tickstodatetime.azurewebsites.net/