Convert type DateTime.Utc.Ticks to DateTime String in SQL
Type     Stamp                     JobIdText   
104      638488466706836320        UL32443fdf
104      20240416074730            ILF20240416074730277A

I have problem when I convert Stamp have a BigInt ( DateTime.Utc.ticks)
I want to convert DateTime
For example:  638488466706836320  => expected result:  20240416072013 ( 2024 04 16 .. )
And I want to update all records that have a stamp like that
UPDATE tableName
SET Stamp = 
    CASE 
        WHEN ISNUMERIC(Stamp) = 1 THEN CAST(Stamp AS BIGINT)
        ELSE Stamp
    END,
    JobIdText = 
    CASE Type
        WHEN 100 THEN 'IU'
        WHEN 101 THEN 'IC'
        WHEN 102 THEN 'ISF'
        WHEN 103 THEN 'IODF'
        WHEN 104 THEN 'ILF'
        WHEN 105 THEN 'SFM'
    END + 
    CASE 
        WHEN ISNUMERIC(Stamp) = 1 THEN CAST(CONVERT(BIGINT, CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), DATEADD(MILLISECOND, CAST(Stamp AS BIGINT) / 10000, '19700101'), 120)) AS NVARCHAR(20))
        ELSE ''
    END + LEFT(NEWID(), 4)
WHERE JobIdText NOT LIKE '%IU%'
  AND JobIdText NOT LIKE '%IC%'
  AND JobIdText NOT LIKE '%ISF%'
  AND JobIdText NOT LIKE '%IODF%'
  AND JobIdText NOT LIKE '%ILF%'
  AND JobIdText NOT LIKE '%SFM%';


error:  Implicit conversion from data type datetime to bigint is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.


https://stackoverflow.com/a/29174667/6299857 - This might help

You should always store dates as Date or DateTime types, never as strings.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.

I didn't say remove the image, replace the image with consumable text; ideally DDL and DML but otherwise a markdown table.

You seem to have an overflow error also declare @stamp bigint = 638488466706836320 select DATEADD(MILLISECOND, CAST(@Stamp AS BIGINT) / 10000, '19700101') 

I see two problems. First, the value you have started with represents the number of 100-nanosecond ticks since January 1, 0001, not 1970. To use that starting date, you will need to use the DATETIME2 type for calculations. Second, the DATEADD() function only accepts an INT value, not a BIGINT. To apply the ticks value with the desired accuracy, you will need to separate the ticks value into multiple components (such as days, seconds, and nanoseconds) and apply each adjustment in sequence.
An alternative is to offset the ticks value by 599266080000000000 to give the number of ticks since 1900-01-01. However, multiple DATEADD() operations are still needed to achieve milliseconds (or even seconds) accuracy.
Finally, if your intent is to convert the resting date/time value into a string "yyyymmddhhmmssfff" having no punctuation, you can use CONVERT(,,121) combined with a series of REPLACE() functions.
The following demonstrates several variations of the above.
DECLARE @Stamp BIGINT = 638488466706836320

SELECT
    -- Maximum accuracy
    DATEADD(day, @Stamp / 864000000000,
       DATEADD(second, @Stamp % 864000000000 / 10000000,
           DATEADD(ns, @Stamp % 10000000 * 100,
               CAST('00010101' AS DATETIME2)
   ))) AS ConvertedDateTime1,

    -- Reduced millisecond accuracy
    DATEADD(day, @Stamp / 864000000000,
        DATEADD(millisecond, @Stamp % 864000000000 / 10000,
            CAST('00010101' AS DATETIME2)
    )) AS ConvertedDateTime2,

    -- Adjused for use with a 1900-01-01 reference date (1/300 second accuracy)
    DATEADD(day, (@Stamp - 599266080000000000) / 864000000000,
        DATEADD(millisecond, (@Stamp - 599266080000000000) % 864000000000 / 10000,
            CAST('19000101' AS DATETIME)
    )) AS ConvertedDateTime3,

    -- Convert to text "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss" and strip punctuation
    REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(23),
        DATEADD(day, @Stamp / 864000000000,
            DATEADD(millisecond, @Stamp % 864000000000 / 10000,
                CAST('00010101' AS DATETIME2)
        )),
        120), '-', ''), ' ', ''), ':', '')
        AS ConvertedDateTime4p % 864000000000 / 10000000,
           DATEADD(ns, @Stamp % 10000000 * 100,
               CAST('00010101' AS DATETIME2)
   ))) AS ConvertedDateTime1,

    -- Reduced millisecond accuracy
    DATEADD(day, @Stamp / 864000000000,
        DATEADD(millisecond, @Stamp % 864000000000 / 10000,
            CAST('00010101' AS DATETIME2)
    )) AS ConvertedDateTime2,

    -- Adjused for use with a 1900-01-01 reference date (1/300 second accuracy)
    DATEADD(day, (@Stamp - 599266080000000000) / 864000000000,
        DATEADD(millisecond, (@Stamp - 599266080000000000) % 864000000000 / 10000,
            CAST('19000101' AS DATETIME)
    )) AS ConvertedDateTime3,

    -- Convert to text "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.fff" and strip punctuation
    REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(23),
        DATEADD(day, @Stamp / 864000000000,
            DATEADD(millisecond, @Stamp % 864000000000 / 10000,
                CAST('00010101' AS DATETIME2)
        )),
        121), '-', ''), ' ', ''), ':', ''), '.', '')
        AS ConvertedDateTime4

Results:



ConvertedDateTime1
ConvertedDateTime2
ConvertedDateTime3
ConvertedDateTime4




2024-04-16 06:44:30.6836320
2024-04-16 06:44:30.6830000
2024-04-16 06:44:30.683
20240416064430



Note: These results are about 35 minutes different from your posted expected value. Please double check the calculations.
See this db<>fiddle for a demo.
I'll leave it to you to chose which calculation works best for you and to merge it back into your original query.
